# Adding cookie session store back to Rails API app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails-API app. More or less "out of the box" but I want to add back cookie-based session store. Here is what I've done:

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
+ include ::ActionController::Cookies
```

config/application.rb

```
+ config.middleware.insert_after ActiveRecord::QueryCache, ActionDispatch::Cookies
+ config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

created config/initializers/secret_token.rb

```
+ Namespace::Application.config.secret_token = 'token'
```

created config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
+ Namespace::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_namespace_key'
```

When I inspect the session in a controller it results:

```
<Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash:0x3fdadc5daa24 not yet loaded>
```

However it does appear that data is being written to and used.

But, in my browser the cookie itself is being named as '_session_id' instead of '_namespace_key'

I thought I added back every piece required for cookie based session storage, but I appear to be missing something else. Any ideas?

Comment: I am also having the same problem, did you disable `api_only` in the end? seems like it isn't a good solution..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to remove these middleware declarations from your `application.rb` file and add this:

```
config.api_only = false
```

This will enable session management the way you want if there is a configured `session_store` somewhere in your initialisers (which you have). This isn't clearly documented, [but that's what you're supposed to do](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/master/lib/rails-api/application.rb#L141).

Example [here](https://github.com/mauricio/sample_api).

Comment: While this may fix the problem, it doesn't really make sense to do.  I use rails-api to keep my stack slim and trim.  Setting `config.api_only = false` essentially says to just use the regular, full Rails stack.  ...in which case, there's no point in using rails-api.

Comment: @turboladen is right--this defeats the purpose of using rails-api.  If you only want to include specific middleware, with specific options, there's a very clean way to do that--the same way rails-api itself does it [here](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/v0.4.0/lib/rails-api/application/default_rails_four_middleware_stack.rb#L13)

Comment: Holy crap!  Praise the lord for this question and answer!  After hours of tracing code, I was about ready to strangle myself, trying to figure out why the #$%^! it wasn't using my session_options! ;)  I'm going to add an alternate option to this answer in case people don't want to disable `api_only`.

Comment: Okay, my edit was rejected, I guess (?) but see @IsaacBetesh's answer below to get the idea.  I also added a PR for Rails Guides to explain the special case of trying to add session middleware back in to a Rails api_only app: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28009

Answer (score 55):

If you're on Rails 5, and want to preserve `config.api_only = true` you could extend the middleware to add the sessions layer, adding this code after `class Application < Rails::Application` in `config/application.rb`

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: '_namespace_key'
```

This could come in handy when you want to have a rails `api-only` enabled app but have to manage user sessions with an administration panel like ActiveAdmin or Rails_Admin.

Comment: To enable ActiveAdmin on a Rails 5 API app, you have to perform a few other steps in addition to the ones above. Specifically, you have to create 2 base controllers, one for ActiveAdmin which inherits from `ActionController::Base` and another for your API controllers which inherits from `ActionController::API`. You also need a few more pieces of middleware to get the dashboard views rendering. I wrote [a guide](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/how-to-add-active-admin-to-a-rails-5-api-application.html?utm_source=stackoverflow) with all the steps. Hope that helps!

Comment: It may be obvious, but the `config.session_store` is no longer useful in this case; only this `config.middleware.use` stuff is required now. In addition, the options like `key: '_namespace_key'` should also be moved to the `config.middleware.use` statements.

Comment: According to this [Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24239#issuecomment-199409912), you may also need to `include AbstractController::Helpers` and `include ActionController::Cookies` in the controller besides enabling the middleware.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me in Rails 6.0, `application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
config.middleware.insert_after(ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore)
```

If you want to set custom key (yes, it has to be set twice):

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: '_your_app'
config.middleware.insert_after(ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: '_your_app')
```

And lastly, if you want to add expiration date - it's done here:

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: '_your_app', expire_after: 20.years 
config.middleware.insert_after(ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: '_your_app')
```

Would have loved linking to documentation, but there's none.

Comment: Plus, it's important to declare this separately on each environment file. Especially if you're using omniauth (depends on the domain which is set on `session_store`).

Answer (score 9):

This line is ignored because you are not using the full Rails stack:

```
::Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
  :key => '_namespace_key'
```

So instead, your session is using the default session key [set here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb#L23).  However, you can pass these arguments directly by replacing:

```
config.middleware.insert_after 
  ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

with:

```
config.middleware.insert_after
  ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore,
  :key => '_namespace_key'
```

Here's [a full list of options you can pass](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L195) (with a rough idea of their defaults, since some may be overridden by modules in Rails).

Answer (score 4):

This thread worked the magic for me. I was on `Rails "7.0.4"` and `Ruby "3.1.2"`

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
```

Below is the User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :jwt_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, 
  :timeoutable, :trackable, jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtDenylist
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what the official Rails documentation suggests ;) https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#using-session-middlewares

Comment: It works beautifully also on Rails 6.0!