# Session in Rails_API gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rails-api

I am using the rails_api gem in my project. I want to add session management for authentication, but it seems the session does not work. Here is my configuration in `config/initializer/session_store.rb`:

```
Pmcapi::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {

  key: '_pmcapi_session', 
  expire_after: 1.hour
}
```

I added `config.api_only = false` in `application.rb` ([Adding cookie session store back to Rails API app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342710/adding-cookie-session-store-back-to-rails-api-app))

and in my `session_controller`, I added session to store the token

```
# session_controller.rb
def create
  #just to generate new token
  user.reset_sso_token!
  session[:token] ||= user.sso_token
  self.current_user = user
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

When in `application_controller`, I want to access `session[:token]` but the result is `nil`:

```
# application_controller.rb
def authenticate_user!
  #puts("User Authentication")
  #puts(request.authorization)
  #puts(request)
  @user = User.authenticate_with_token(session[:token])
  #head :unauthorized unless @user.present?
  redirect_to sign_in_path if @user.nil?
end
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Upvoted for increased exposure.

Comment: Did you solved the issue? https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/pull/97

Comment: Also leaving this for reference: https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/issues/73

Answer (score 2):

from what I can see from your `config.api_only = false` line this basically makes rails use the full stack rather than keeping it slim, which is the main reason you could be using `rails-api` So I suggest trying something like

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Session::Cookie
```

in your application controller.

If that doesn't work I recommend drawing your attention to [This pull request about session management in the rails 4 stack](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/pull/97)

Comment: I would take this a step further: `config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies; config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore`, and then of course, you'll have to configure both--let me know if you want an example of configuring them and I'll post it in a separate answer.  If you do this, it will be easier to integrate `devise`.

Comment: This save me. but, only works in application.rb, no in application_controller, not as you say...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pmcapi::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_pmcapi_session', expire_after: 1.hour
can you try this in config/initializer/session_store.rb

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use well supported and documented gems rather than write my own code. the reasons for this are:

1. It saves you time
2. It saves you money
3. It is more maintainable
4. Other coders who work on your projects will more likely be familiar with what you have implemented.
5. Its more secure because (at least in my case) many more people with more experience than I have, have been working on it for a number of years.

With all of that out of the way I would highly recommend you use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or one of the other well established authentication gems rather than wrestle with this kind of thing on your own.

I found this article helpful

http://www.emilsoman.com/blog/2013/05/18/building-a-tested/