# Rails cookie not being set in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie in my controller quick is equal to a POST param value. I've tried `cookies[:email] = params[:email]`. When a user does a POST to this controller the `params[:email]` is present. When the page renders after this however, the cookie isn't visible.

Other dummy cookies I've set are also not visible, and Only visible when I soft refresh the page. If I empty the cache and Do a hard reload no cookie is visible. If I just hit enter in the browser URL again, the cookie is present, however the email param has been lost, so that cookie isn't set.

Can anyone clarify what I'm missing? I read one SO post saying to do a redirect back to this page, however that isn't working for me either.

Comment: What version of rails?

Comment: Hi, I'm using 4.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710896/rails-4-sessions-cookie-is-not-set ?

Comment: Do you have any supporting code? Are you using Warden, devise? Do you have users? Is your `secret_key_base` present? Are you signing or encrypting the cookies? Any CSRF information?