# ActiveAdmin cannot authorize in rails-api project

Tags: activeadmin, rails-api

I've created a new rails-api 4.2.1 project and try to make ActiveAdmin working with it.

I see that admin_user is authorized but after redirect to a dashboard 401 is returned ...

Comment: Instead of disabling `api_only` mode altogether (which kind of defeats the purpose of creating an API app in the first place), you can selectively add middleware that allows ActiveAdmin to work while keeping your API controllers using the slimmed-down stack. [Here is a guide](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/how-to-add-active-admin-to-a-rails-5-api-application.html?utm_source=stackoverflow) to **enable ActiveAdmin to work with a Rails 5 API application**. Not sure if it works exactly the same for `rails-api` 4.x, but it may be similar. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Adding

> config.api_only = false

to application.rb solved the issue.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342710/adding-cookie-session-store-back-to-rails-api-app/15363386#15363386)