# OmniAuth::NoSessionError (You must provide a session to use OmniAuth.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth, omniauth

I try use omniauth-facebook, but when i add in my devise.rb:

`config.omniauth :facebook, 'my app id', 'my app secret'`

i get error OmniAuth::NoSessionError (You must provide a session to use OmniAuth.):

I haven't idea what i can do it.

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37140228/5004690

Comment: you use omniauth-facebook, but add `config.omniauth :github`? you should use `config.omniauth :facebook`

Comment: sorry, i copied this, i use :facebook :)

Comment: @TamerB Thank You !